# How to compile a Latex document on NixOS?

Tags: software-installation, pdf, latex, nixos

I normally use `pdflatex` to compile latex documents, but on NixOS I do not see that `pdflatex` is available to install via `$ nix-env -i pdflatex`.

```
$ nix-env -qa pdflatex
error: selector ‘pdflatex’ matches no derivations
```

Results for `pdflatex` do not appear under search at [nixos.org/nixos/packages.html](https://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html) either. However,  I did notice there the package `rubber`, which apparently wraps other latex programs including `pdflatex`. After installing `rubber` and attempting to compile my latex document with it I get the following "pdflatex is not found" error.

```
$ rubber --pdf doc.tex
compiling doc.tex...
pdflatex not found
Running pdflatex failed.
```

**How can I install pdflatex to compile latex documents on NixOS?**

**Why is `rubber` available for installation via `nix-env` whereas `pdflatex`, a dependency of `rubber`, is not?**

As a side-note, the ['Tex/Latex' section of the manual](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/TexLive) does not explain this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're linking some ancient version of manual.  It's explained in recent versions: http://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-language-texlive

```
nix-env -iA nixos.texlive.combined.scheme-basic
```

It is also explained the NixOS wiki: https://nixos.wiki/wiki/TexLive

Comment: Or, on non-NixOS: `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.texlive.combined.scheme-basic` (will throw `LaTeX Error: File 'lmodern.sty' not found.` though, and couldn't figure out how to link it after installing `nix-env -i lmodern`, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201207/unable-to-compile-pdf-in-r-studio-latex-error-file-lmodern-sty-not-found).)

Comment: You need to use the `.combine` function instead of installing TeX Live packages separately.

Comment: I see the same error pointed out by @toraritte even on NixOS 19.09.

Comment: @Ashesh: the answer is still the same.  As TeX Live upstream designed it, `scheme-basic` is very small and does *not* include Latin Modern.  It's in that manual how you can mix your own combination.  If you want a simple "solution", just install a larger scheme instead, e.g. `scheme-small` does contain this font if I look correctly.

Comment: @VladimírČunát yeah, that's what I did in the end; it works with `scheme-medium` and not small.